# difference Tuple<int, double> vs. (int, double)

Tags: c#, tuples, multiple-variable-return

What is the difference in using

```
Tuple<int, double> myTuple = new Tuple<int, double>(3, 5.0);
```

and

```
(int, double) myCombinedVariable = (3, 5.0);
```

in `C#`?
And most important: Are there any differences regarding performance?

Comment: `(int, double)` is `ValueTuple` under the hood

Comment: Indeed - and note the difference between `ValueTuple` (mutable value type) and `Tuple` (shallow-immutable reference type).